# select based on session

Tags: php, mysql, session

How do I select a value from a database where username is based on the session?

This is what I have so far:

```
$query = mysql_query ("select id from CUSTOMER where username = .$_SESSION['username'] ");
```

Comment: Note that you need to escape the user name using `mysql_real_escape_string()` at some point.

Comment: @Pekka: Generally a good advice although we don’t know where the value of `$_SESSION['username']` came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = mysql_query("select id from CUSTOMER where username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
```

Comment: nevermind I read in haste...Didn't know his table was actually called CUSTOMER

Answer (score 3):

If username is in session cookie then grab the username like this

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$escuname = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$query = mysql_query("select id from CUSTOMER where username = '".$escuname."' LIMIT 1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Session variable in your query wasn't parsed properly. You could fix it using curly bracers syntax:

```
$query = mysql_query( "select id from CUSTOMER where username = '{$_SESSION[ "username" ]}'" );
```

or concatenate it using dot operator:

```
$query = mysql_query ( "select id from CUSTOMER where username = '" . $_SESSION[ "username" ] . "'" );
```

You can find more about [parsing strings in PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).